# How do I specify in HTML or CSS that a table column should have the minimum width

Tags: html, css, html-table

How do I specify in HTML or CSS that a table column should have the minimum width with respect to column content.

I have tried [max-width](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-width.asp) but doesn't work

```
.p
{
max-width:10px;
background-color:yellow;
}

<table> ...
<td nowrap class="p">text</td>
...<table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I specify in HTML or CSS that a table column should have the minimum width with >respect to column content.

did you try **min-width** instead? you used max-width in your CSS.

Comment: looks like min-width doesn't work. just use width: "In CSS 2.1, the effect of 'min-width' and 'max-width' on tables, inline tables, table cells, table columns, and column groups is undefined."  (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#min-max-widths)

Answer (score 1):

Change the code as follows:

```
.p{
    display: inline-block;
    ...
}
```

[Here's an example of that code in action.](http://jsfiddle.net/2Ud8C/)

Answer (score 0):

I see it's a while since you posted this question, but I just ran into the same issue myself.

What appears to work is to give the column an explicit width that is smaller than the minimum, like say

```
<td width="10">
```

The browser attempts to use this width, discovers that it is less than the minimum width, and so overrides it with the minimum width. This is documented behavior and it worked for me in IE, Firefox, and Chrome.

I'd prefer something cleaner, like "width=minimum", but I guess if it works what more can you ask for.